# How can I catch the fontSize change event?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I am writing a skin for a `TextInput` control, and I want it to change when the `fontSize` style changes dynamically. I see this is done in the default `TextInputSkin` but couldn't decipher the behavior form the code.

How is this done?

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

override `fontSize` setter, and dispatch a CHANGE event there.