# How to detect font change inside iFrame

Tags: jquery, iframe

Is there a way to detect font change inside iFrame? For example if font size inside iFrame currently is 13px. And lets say an event changed the font size to 15px. Is there any way i can capture this? Something like this:

```
if(iFrame.fontChange == '15px'){
//Do something... 
}
```

Comment: The font size of what exactly? And is the iframe running on your domain?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692094/how-can-i-catch-the-fontsize-change-event

Comment: And how exactly do you expect the font size to be changed? By user zooming in the page or else?

Comment: @arunes That's overly wrong suggestion - it deals with Flex (Flash), not jQuery...

Answer (score 3):

There is not such event which will get triggered whenever font size changes on the page. But if you want to know the `fontSize` of any element you can try this.

```
var fontSize = $('elementSelector').css('fontSize');
```

I hope this helps you.

If you want to find any element inside the `iframe` which is in the same domain then you can try this.

```
 var fontSizeInsideIframe = $('elementSelector', $('iframeSelector').contents()).css('fontSize');
```

Comment: he asked for the event of font-resizing inside an iframe.

Comment: Check my answer before down voting. Care to remove the down vote?

Comment: +1 stabilizing the downs.. :) this is a lead for figuring out how to do this. There are NO! normalized event's to detect it. But with this code snippet you are half the way. Now you know how to check the size. All you'll have to do is to wrap this in a interval .

Comment: @ShankarSangoli - So there is no event that can find out if the text size has been changed inside iFrame?

Comment: @NoviceMe - Yes, there is not such event provided by any browser as of now.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli - See problem is when the text changes to 15px i see scrollbars on iframe. Is there any way to detect that? I just want to remove those scrollbars.

Comment: How does the font size changes? Do you do it programmatically or user does it?